# windows forms - form freezes when a time-consuming operation takes place

Tags: winforms, events

I'm kind of new to Windows Forms. The Windows Forms app I've created is the front-end to a component that does very time-consuming data transformation tasks. The data transformation task emits events which the form subscribes to.

When the form receives an event, it alters the text in a label and calls `Refresh()` for that label.

When I run the process from the form, it remains responsive and updates the label text for maybe a minute or so. After that, it simply freezes and Windows declares the process 'Unresponsive' until the data transformation is finished, at which time the form unfreezes and the label shows that the data transformation is complete (as expected).

I haven't put the data transformation onto a separate thread - is this the first thing I should try? Can events cross threads? If not, what else should I do?

Comment: can you show some of your code..? is this something that you could possibly do using Threading..?

Comment: Which version of .NET?  Newer versions have additional options you can use for threading.  At any rate, yes, threading is your first option.  See this post for ideas.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464338/multithreading-libraries-for-net

Comment: .NET 4. I see no reason why the work couldn't be done on another thread. It reads data from text files, transforms it, and writes it out to other text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, threading is where you should be working.  Multi threading in WinForms, depending on your version, can be tricky.

If you're using .NET 4.0 or higher, you could be using the [Microsoft Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Otherwise, there is a good article, [here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx), from C# Corner that covers threading in WinForms applications that I'd suggest as a starting point.

The [BackgroundWorker](http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/implementing-multi-threading-in-winforms-using-the-backgroundworker-class/) is another option for simplifying threading in WinForms.

Comment: You links are a massive bunch of stuff I knew nothing about. Your post has been most helpful - thank you.

Comment: That's why we're here.  Good luck!